# how to add string into variable json string for add flag in highstock chart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

i have problem when add string into variable json string, the script is like this :

```
    var  myNewData4 =[];
    for (var i = 0, l = row; i < l; i++) {
      myNewData4 = [{
            x: datatime[i],
            y: 44,
            title: datalayer[i],
            obj: 'fff'
        }];

    }
```

when I run that script always failed stretcher. I use that script to add data flag in highstock chart,

this is part of script for create highstock chart for add Flags :

```
       {
            type: 'flags',
            name: 'Flags on series',
            data: myNewData4,
            onSeries: 'dataseries',
            shape: 'squarepin',
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }
```

if i use that script like the script below without for loop is succes, highstock chart can read.

```
      var  myNewData4 =[]       
      myNewData4 = [{
            x: 1360774800000,
            y: 44,
            title: 'BRF',
            obj: 'fff'
        }];
```

how to add string into variable json string with loop for to add flag in highstock chart ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
var  myNewData4 =[];
for (var i = 0, l = row; i < l; i++) {
    //since myNewData4 is an array, push a new object into it.
    myNewData4.push({
        x: datatime[i],
        y: 44,
        title: datalayer[i],
        obj: 'fff'
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since your code with setting the array directly works, following comes to mind:
Do you get a reference/out-of-bounds error in your javascript engine when trying to access datatime[i] or datalayer[i]?

Comment: I've tried to like it but in highstock chart can not read it, is there another way?

Comment: when accessing datatime[i] or datalayer[i] i check with firebug but there is no error but accessing the data appears only the last row alone. there are thousands of row data should

Comment: What I else could think of: is datatime[i] a number, and datalayer[i] a string like in your example?

Comment: yes, in my data datatime[i] is a number, and datalayer[i] a string

Comment: Then, if you have the loop like Ted Hopp or I suggested, I can't think of anything else that causes your issue at the moment.

Comment: Shion, do you know how to add data flag in highstock chart using the json ?

Comment: You should prepare json like in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-placement/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work better:

```
var  myNewData4 =[];
for (var i = 0, l = row; i < l; i++) {
  myNewData4.push({
        x: datatime[i],
        y: 44,
        title: datalayer[i],
        obj: 'fff'
    });
}
```

That will give you an array of `row` objects, instead of an array of a single object.

Comment: I've tried to like it but in highstock chart can not read it, is there another way?

Comment: srry Ted, I edited the question above for more details, is there another way?

Comment: @user2285134 - In your original code, the loop is pointless. Each time through the loop you _replace_ `myNewData4` with a new, 1-element array. (If your posted code is incomplete and you are actually using each array in the loop, that's a different story. The only thing I can think of that will cause a problem is that `datatime[i]` and/or `datalayer[i]` is undefined for some value(s) of `i`.)

Comment: Ted Hopp, do you know how to add data flag in highstock chart using the json ?

Comment: Ted, how Each time through the loop don't replace myNewData4 with a new ?

Comment: @PrioWahono - Sorry, I know very little about using highstock. If you use `push` as I showed in my code, then `myNewData4` will be an array of multiple (x, y, title, obj) objects. What part(s) of the highstock api are you using?

Comment: i use series->type->flags in highcharts.StockChart.
Title & obj  is just additional parameter for description in chart